# How does Parse Server determine what APNS push certificate to use?

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

How does Parse Server internally decide on which APNS push certificate to use? (development vs production)

Answer (score 0):

The server uses the apn node module and will try every certificates to issue your notification in order.